# Perform a compare and assign values between two nested-data structures in python using pure python

Tags: python-3.x, nested-lists

I currently have two datasets (database, assignment) which are nested list-dict and dict-list respectively. I would like to use a sort of vlookup function of a specific key in database, and if the key:value matches a key in assignment, I would like to create a new key-value pair in the original database (sort of assigning someone a task to do, based on their jobscope).
I would like to complete this using purely python without importing any libraries (no pandas/numpy etc.)

To explain abit clearer, heres my code and what im trying to achieve:

```py
database = \[{‘name’ : ’ABC’, ‘position’ : ‘executive’}, {‘name’ : ’DEF’, ‘position’ : ‘senior exec’}, {‘name’ : ’GEH’, ‘position’ : ‘contractor’}\]

assignment =  { 'executive': \[‘task1', ‘task2’\], 
    ‘senior exec’: \[‘task3', ‘task4’\] , 
    'contractor': \[‘task5'\]}
```

Im thinking the code should be follow an if-else logic similar to a vlookup, something like this --

```py
if database\[‘position’\] == assignment\[‘executive’\] 
    create new key – ‘jobscope’ and assign task1, task2 as a list etc.
```

the output im expecting is something like this:

```
database = \[{‘name’ : ’ABC’, ‘position’ : ‘executive’, ‘jobscope’ : \[‘task1', ‘task2’\]}, {‘name’ : ’DEF’, ‘position’ : ‘senior exec’, ‘jobscope’ : \[‘task3', ‘task4’\]}, {‘name’ : ’GEH’, ‘position’ : ‘contractor’, ‘jobscope’ : \[‘task5'\]}\]
```

I’m not sure how to achieve this looping and producing output, also I have some flexibility to change the data structure of **assignment** so I seek your advice if a dict-list is the best way to achieve this output as well?

Comment: the example seems to have used `\` a lot which is invalid in the code.  do consider correcting this as best as possible.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should work:

```
database = [
    {'name': 'ABC', 'position': 'executive'},
    {'name': 'DEF', 'position': 'senior exe'},
    {'name': 'GEH', 'position': 'contractor'},
]

assignment = {
    'executive': ['task1', 'task2'],
    'senior exec': ['task3', 'task4'],
    'contractor': ['task5'],
}

for dictionary in database:
    if dictionary['position'] in assignment.keys():
        dictionary['jobscope'] = assignment[dictionary['position']]

print(database)
```